# ASP.NET Сore 2.0 действие по умолчанию

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, маршрутизация, asp.net-core-2

Пишу приложение с возможностью регистрации и входа через обычную HTML форму.

На главной странице приложения будет соответствующие кнопки, я хочу чтобы по нажатию на них пользователя перекидывало на `xxx.com/registration` и `xxx.com/login` соответственно, где будет подружатся новая форма с полями, кнопками, все дела.

Но есть проблема, для того чтобы обратится к методу, который возвращает эту самую форму, нужно писать URL такого типа:  `xxx.com/registration/registration` или `xxx.com/login/login`, т.е обращаться к контроллеру, а потом к методу.

ВОПРОС: Как сделать так, чтобы не нужно было указывать имя метода в URL, тем самым писать такие некрасивые пути `xxx.com/registration/registration`, как сделать так, чтобы нужно было обращаться только к контроллеру `xxx.com/registration`, после чего подгружалась нужная форма?

Comment: Зарегистрируйте для этих контроллеров маршруты, в которыx экшн методы по умолчанию имеют нужное название. Или назовите эти методы `Index`.

Comment: Не подкинете пример кода? я сейчас читаю статью на metanit - но ничего понять не могу

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Первое решение** это в вашем контроллере сделать действие с названием `Index`, в этом случае в пути его можно не указывать, и путь `site.ru/controllerName` будет автоматически идти к действию `Index`.

Это поведение прописано в маршруте по умолчанию, обычно в файле `startup.cs`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

**Второе решение** это создать специальный маршрут для этого

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "myRoute",
                /* шаблон маршрута */
                template: "registration"; 
                /* куда отправим запрос по этому шаблону */
                defaults: new { controller = "registration", action = "myRegistrationAction" }); 
        });
```

[Основы маршрутизации в ASP.NET Core.](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/11.1.php)

**Третий вариант** задавать маршруты с помощью атрибутов:

```
[Route("registration")]
public IActionResult AnyActionName()
```

[Атрибуты маршрутизации.](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/11.6.php)

Comment: а первое решение разве будет работать без дополнительных настроек? Стоило тогда уже и про [маршрутизацию с помощью атрибутов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing) сказать

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, сделал

Comment: 3-й вариант отлично сработал, спасибо.